# Ajax request not working in joomla component mvc

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, joomla-extensions

i send a ajax request to joomla component controller but not getting any return data

**controller**

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class igalleryControllerajaxraw extends JControllerLegacy
{

    public function ajaxrequest()
    {

    try
    {
      echo $anyParam = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('name');


    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {

    }
 }
}
```

**Ajax Request**

```
 jQuery.ajax({ 
         type: "get",
         data:"name=myname",
         url: "index.php?option=com_igallery&task=ajaxraw.ajaxrequest",  
         success: function (data) {  
          alert(data);
         }

    });
```

i do every possible things but not getting solution

Comment: Did you get any errors in logs?

Comment: no i am not getting any error in log

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your problem. But an idea to find the problem. You can use Chrome's built in developer console or Firebug addon on firefox. They will show the ajax request when invoked, and all reports related to the Javascript errors, Get/POST request done trough ajax . You can find whether the Ajax request result in http error looking in to its HTTP status code of the request .